# folder will not open

Tags: 2.2-froyo, motorola-droid-x, home-screen-folders

I have organized my Apps into several folders.  Every once in a while, I find that when I click on a folder, nothing happens (i.e. the folder does not open).  No matter what I do, I cannot open the folder until I reboot the phone.  Other folders still seem to open when this happens.

I have a Droid X, not rooted, runnning Froyo (2.2.1).  I am using the stock Home screen launcher, and have not installed any alternative launchers.

Anyone else have this problem?  It does not seem to be folder specific, as it affects different folders at different times.

Comment: I would try a different launcher, if only for the sake of testing, and see if it has the same problem. MotoBLUR can be a bit buggy, although, it has gotten better since its initial release. If you try a different launcher, and still have the issue, then it could be something else causing the problem. I dont use folders that often, and haven't experienced this issue, which is why I am only commenting on the question.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the folder and re-creating it again to see if the problem still persists?

Comment: Just wondering if you tried another launcher and still have the same problem. If you have, can you update your question with the results of the test?

Comment: I've tried ADW and Launcher Pro.  Though I never used either of them long enough to know for certain that the problem never occurs.  Unfortunately the folder issue is not very repeatable and takes a lot of use before it even occurs.

Comment: I've had this problem as well. Deleting folder and recreating contents is painful and ineffective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to settings->applications->all, then long press menu button, type launcher, press on the result, then press 'force stop'. It will automatically restart, and you'll get your folder back

Comment: I haven't had this problem in a while, but I think this may be the best solution if it happens again.  Thanks for the suggestion.